# Mosquito clear retained mojibake topic

Tags: unicode, ascii, mqtt, mosquitto, mojibake

I've published an mojibake topic because of my crash program, the ��� part is some random byte codes, e.g.

```
test/���������������/yoyoyo qqq
```

And if I want to clear it, I type something like

```
mosquitto_pub -t test/���������������/yoyoyo -r -n
```

But this didn't work, because these � character is not the original �, these codec is mismatch in ascii and unicode so present as � character.

How can I clear these retain message without delete the whole retain file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't work out what the actual char you can capture them and play them back into mosquitto_pub with something like this:

```
mosquitto_sub -v -C 1 -N -t 'test/+/yoyoyo' > file.txt
```

This will save to the file the topic and the payload of the first message that matches the pattern. There will be a space between the topic and paylaod.

You can then edit the file to remove the payload and leave just the topic (on a line on it's own with no new line at the end) and save this as `edited_file.txt`

You can then feed this back into `mosquitto_pub`, add -n flag (null message) and -r flag (retain message)

```
mosquitto_pub -t `cat edited_file.txt` -r -n
```

Comment: Thank you @hardillb! I've removed that topic! but the publish comment should add an -r flag, I have edited for you :)